# JMeter not recording on IE, records on Chrome and Firefox

Tags: jmeter, oracle-adf

I'm using Apache JMeter for recording an ADF Application deployed on WebLogicServer ver. 10.3.6 using JMeter 2.10. JMeter is not recording any http requests when the application is run on IE ver. 10, whereas it records on Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox. My JDeveloper version is 11.1.2.4 and using Oracle's ADF 11g

Answer (score 0):

Out of interest, why do you need to record application on IE? The calls should be all the same independent of browser being used. If you need requests to contain IE 10 agent string you may wish to consider HTTP Header Manager

IE 10 User Agent looks as follows:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/6.0)
```

However if you're intending to perform a cross-browser testing you need to look into [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) automation framework. There is a possibility to launch [Selenium from within JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler) as well.